# C# UWP connect to tcp client via socket

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sockets, uwp, uwp-xaml

When I will start a connection in a UWP application via socket and a tcp protocol, I will get a `Access denied` exception.

When I do this with a Windows Form Application I have with the same code no issues.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the **Private Networks (Client & Server)** capability to your app:

From [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/enable-device-capabilities):

- In Visual Studio Solution Explorer, double-click the package manifest
  file, Package.appxmanifest.
- Open the Capabilities tab.
- Select the device capabilities that your app uses.

Comment: Thank you!I will test it later

Comment: @Freeman, is it working for you? If so, please mark the question as solved.

Comment: Yes, sorry I had test it for few minutes and thank you for your answer!